# How to create custom keyboard with symbols?

Tags: android, keyboard

How to create custom keyboard with symbols like(%,&,(,),@,..)? And also i would like to add number and alphabets in custom keyboard..

Comment: this could help you http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html

Comment: See this link:[Create Your Own Custom Keyboard for Android Devices](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for-android-devices/)

Comment: Have checked the example found within sdk in apidemos? that is all you need.

Comment: can you please explain briefly?

Comment: check inside your andorid sdk under samples android-sdk-windows\samples\android-7\SoftKeyboard you can also install the apidemos to your emulator and check how it works or may be it will be already there in your emulator.

Comment: This link code was working. But in emulator that custom keyboard is coming. But in device i was using galaxy tab, tab2. In that device the default keyboard only coming. Is there any solution to run in device?

Comment: I want to run my application in device(galaxy tab2). Not in emulator.

Comment: you have to go to settings --> Locale and text --> enable your new keyboard by clicking the checkbox

Comment: In that local and text only samsung keyboard, chinese keyboard,swype only is there..

Comment: your keyboard is installed in the device??

Comment: ya.. It was installed.. but if i am trying to run means the default keyboard only will showing. But im emulator it was working fine.

Comment: I think that keyboard only works inside that activity

Answer (score 0):

This   [DEMO](http://code.google.com/p/extkeyboardremapper/source/checkout)
is give you your solution. this is a link of svn project. if you had configured svn in you eclipse that import project by put this link :- http://extkeyboardremapper.googlecode.com/svn/trunk.

And If you dont have Svn connection you can get project from [Here](https://github.com/zeuxisoo/android-emoji-keyboard)